# Index on view (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have two tables, `tab_a` and `tab_b`.

And I create a view like the following:

```
create view join_tabs as
(
  select col_x as col_z from tab_a
  union
  select col_y as col_z from tab_b
);
```

And if I do the following:

```
select * from join_tabs where col_z = 'BLAH';
```

If `tab_a` indexes `col_x` and `tab_b` indexes `col_y`, we should be able to do this with two index searches.

However, it would be nice if I could make an index over both tables in one index, or even index the view, in a way that automatically updates immediately if the source tables (`tab_a` or `tab_b`) change.

Is there a way to do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not up-to-par with Oracle but I believe [Materialized Views](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96520/mv.htm#45788) do exactly that.

#### Choosing Indexes for Materialized Views

> The two most common operations on a
>   materialized view are query execution
>   and fast refresh, and each operation
>   has different performance
>   requirements. Query execution might
>   need to access any subset of the
>   materialized view key columns, and
>   might need to join and aggregate over
>   a subset of those columns.
>   Consequently, query execution usually
>   performs best if a single-column
>   bitmap index is defined on each
>   materialized view key column.
>
> In the case of materialized views
>   containing only joins using fast
>   refresh, Oracle recommends that
>   indexes be created on the columns that
>   contain the rowids to improve the
>   performance of the refresh operation.
>
> If a materialized view using
>   aggregates is fast refreshable, then
>   an index is automatically created
>   unless USING NO INDEX is specified in
>   the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
>   statement.

Comment: Can this materialized view be made to update immediately on source views changing? Is that what 'fast refresh' does?

Comment: @Clinton - "Fast refresh" means that the data is updated incrementally.  "Refresh on commit" in a materialized view definition means that the data is updated when the source table changes are committed-- the refresh is synchronous with the commit.  Refresh on commit requires a fast refresh but a fast refresh does not imply refresh on commit.

Comment: @Justin, thank you for the clarification. OP needs the "Refresh on commit" but now you got me wondering what an incremental update is. I assumed that, like SQL Server, a select from a materialized view would *always* return the same results as the select that created the view. Was my assumption wrong?

Comment: An incremental update means that only the changes made to the underlying table are applied to refresh the MV rather than re-executing the entire query to refresh the MV.  This requires that MV logs exist on the base tables and that the MV be sufficiently simple to allow incremental updates.  It is entirely possible for a query against a MV to return different results than a query against the base tables.  Frequently, for example, MVs are used to replicate data from one system to another where there is a lag between changes being made at the source and appearing at the destination.

Comment: @Justin - You should make an answer out of this so I can delete mine. You have my vote.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot create an index on a view, since a view is merely a mask on some tables(s). To do so, create a materialized view as specified by @Lieven and create an index on it.