# Using partition by to get count in Oracle

Tags: oracle, partition

I have a EMP table. I need to get number of employees in each department grouped by country name = 'INDIA','USA', 'AUSTRALIA'.

For example,

```
DEPARTMENT   | #EMPLOYEE(INDIA) | #EMPLOYEE(USA) | # EMPLOYEE(AUSTRALIA)    
ACCOUNTING   | 5                |2               | 3
IT           | 5                |2               | 1
BUSINESS     | 1                |4               | 3
```

I need to use Partition BY to do it. I am able to use PARTITION by to get the total count of employees for each department. But I am not able to subgroup by country name.

Please give me suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: That is the example of current table or desire output? we need both. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: That is the desired output. Thank you. Current table has Employee ID, Name, Country, Department, Salary.

Comment: No, you do not need to use "partition by" anything. What you do need is to get the result in your requirement; how you do that is not required. Besides, in this case "partition by" would not help anyway. What you need is `PIVOT` - except that if you don't know the number and names (and desired order) of all countries ahead of time, you will not be able to do this in "regular" SQL, you will need **dynamic** SQL.

Comment: @mathguy after reading again `need to use Partition BY` sound more like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider conditional count.

```
SELECT  DEPARTMENT,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'INDIA' THEN 1 END) as emp_india,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'USA' THEN 1 END) as emp_usa,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'AUSTRALIA' THEN 1 END) as emp_australia
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: With the caution that this approach only works if the number of countries, their names and their order are given ahead of time. Otherwise dynamic SQL can't be avoided. (Unless one chooses to avoid the de-normalized output in the first place, or has the good sense to use reporting tools for this task, rather than SQL.)

Comment: @mathguy I agree, but the countries are know here. Also why you say country order has anything to do here?

Comment: I am not sure about countries being known (or departments for that matter). Maybe they are, or maybe the OP showed only a representative set of data. Order: is the order in which the columns will appear. Presumably they should appear in *some* order, such as alphabetically or by number of total employees or who knows by what other rule or set of rules. Businesses have their weird requirements...

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thank you for your prompt reply. It works like charm. However, the data is huge and hence, it is taking a bit long time. Perhaps this is why I was told to use Partition.

Comment: Do you have index on `country` and `department` ?

Comment: And, to clarify: If the countries must appear alphabetically, that is known beforehand and is not a problem; but if the columns (countries) must appear by total number of employees in each country, from left to right, then that still requires dynamic SQL, even if the number and names of countries are known beforehand.

Comment: No..there is no index. I am querying from a view.

Comment: maybe consider materialized view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531564/index-on-view-oracle